# A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type" error - vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a  function that  prints the time to an excel in  5 lots each. I have a function that first stores time in collection object and then converts it to an array & finally this function would call another function to populate the array in to excel.

Below my function for your reference.

```
Public daytime_store As New Collection
Public daytime_tm As New Collection
Public daytime_store_cnt As New Collection
Option Explicit

Function n50_store_day()
Dim I_day As Date, Currtime_cutoff As Date, daytime_store_arr As Variant, daytime_tm_arr As Variant, lx As Integer, ly As Integer


I_day = Format(Now(), "hh:mm:ss")
daytime_store.Add I_day
If daytime_store.Count = 5 Then
daytime_store_cnt.Add 5
ly = daytime_store_cnt.Count
If ly = 1 Then lx = 1
If ly > 1 Then lx = ((ly - 1) * 5) + 1
daytime_store_arr = CollectionToArray(daytime_store)
Set daytime_store = New Collection
Call varitoxl(daytime_store_arr, lx)

End If
End Function
```

This is working perfectly if i run the function from F5 but showing wrong data type error if called from a spread sheet. Would anyone guide on this.

Also below function of varitoxl:

```
Function varitoxl(dlr As Variant, yz As Integer) As Variant

Dim strFilename As String: strFilename = "C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\n50imp\book1.xlsx"
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFilename)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("sheet1")
Debug.Print 1
ws.Cells(yz, 1).Resize(5, 1) = dlr
Debug.Print 2
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Function
```

Comment: 1. `Call` is deprecated. Learn not to use it. 2. What is `varitoxl`? My money is on the lack of qualified range/cell use  within that routine. 3. What is `CollectionToArray`? 4. `Option Explicit` should be above the declarations. But kudos for including it!

Comment: varitoxl is a sub that populates array to excel.  Collection to array is a sub that convets collection to array .  I have also added varitoxl sub/function for your reference.

Comment: What line does the error appear on. See my point 4 - using Option Explicit should allow you to debug the code and highlight the error line.

Comment: Need the `CollectionToArray` code as well. There are some issues with your coding of `varitoxl` - you are calling a function that does not return a value and you are closing the ActiveWorkbook, not the one you opened (no guarantees they are the same thing). However, I can't see these being your direct issue.

Comment: Neither of your functions return any value...  And you cannot run a function as a UDF which does anything other than return a value to the calling cell(s) - that includes other subs or functions (such as `varitoxl`) called from your UDF.

Comment: Yes, the issue is with function returning no value. Thanks for pointing out it.

Comment: The real issue is that you can't call `varitoxl` from a UDF.